# Closing opened toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

How to add a function which will close active div in toggle when you click on another a element from menu.

Here is code:

http://jsfiddle.net/t4JAT/

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv1").hide();
        $(".show_hide1").show();

    $('.show_hide1').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
    });

});
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
        $(".show_hide2").show();

    $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    });

});
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv3").hide();
        $(".show_hide3").show();

    $('.show_hide3').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv3").slideToggle();
    });

});​
```

Comment: In this format, this question is super localized!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/t4JAT/4/

Please avoid so many document ready calls you just need one in your page.

rest below should help.

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv1,.slidingDiv2, .slidingDiv3").hide();
        $(".show_hide1,.show_hide2, .show_hide3").show();


    $('.show_hide1').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv2,.slidingDiv3").hide();
         $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
    });


    $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv1,.slidingDiv3").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    });



    $('.show_hide3').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv1,.slidingDiv2").hide();
         $(".slidingDiv3").slideToggle();
    });

});​
```

Comment: This works for me only in jsFiddle. When I try to use this code in html site all div`s are opened in html preview. For testing purposes I deleted all other JavaScript codes but it seems that other problem is presented and this don`t want to hide/slide divs

Comment: Hmm @Marko can you please try replicating it in jsfiddle, or you might be missing a library or something small? let me know how it goes

Comment: @Marko lol cool now don't forget to accept the answer and up vote :) <see I told you so :))>

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs in jquery like this:

**For this import css and js file of jqueryui then use this:**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I know, but tabs are not solution which will be used so toggle elements fits better for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided You can add

```
 $('div[class^=slidingDiv]').hide();
```

What the above line does is select all `divs` which have a `class name` that starts with `slidingDiv` and hide them which are Content divs in this case.

In every `click` event handlers to close all div first which will necessarily hide any content div currently open.

One thing, you can stuff all you code in one `document ready` like

```
 $(function(){
    //all your code goes here
 })
```

To check if it's working check for `Lorem1` in `div1`, `Lorem2` in `div2` and `Lorem3` in `div23`. Changed that to verify.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/t4JAT/5/)